# Navigation as a separate page in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, navigation, nav

I am using my **Navigation** as a separate page which is `Navigation.php` and I am adding this page by `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>` in everypage.
But when I am going on a page, for example: going to **About** page, that **About** button in navigation bar have a class `class='active'` and that class adding by javascript.
The problem is coming when I am going to 2nd level page like:
`Portfolio` > `Portfolio Item`
That script is not adding class on `Portfolio` button.
**`Navigation.php` page:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
    <li <?php echo (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>>
        <a class="nav-item nav" href="/home">
            Home
        </a>
    </li>
    <li <?php echo (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'about.php') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>>
        <a class="nav-item"  href="/about">
            About
        </a>
    </li>
    <li <?php echo (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'services.php') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>>
        <a class="nav-item"  href="/services">
            Services
        </a>
    </li>
    <li <?php if ((basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '.php')) == 'portfolio' or 'portfolioItem') echo "class='active'";?>>
        <a class="nav-item"  href="/portfolio">
            Portfolio
        </a>
    </li>
    <li <?php echo (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'showcase.php') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>>
        <a class="nav-item"  href="/showcase">
            Showcase
        </a>
    </li>
    <li <?php echo (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'blog.php') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>>
        <a class="nav-item"  href="/blog">
            Blog
        </a>
    </li>
    <li <?php echo (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'contact.php') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>>
        <a class="nav-item"  href="/contact">
            Contact
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**`Javascript` I'm using:**

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
      $("nav-pills ul li").each(function () {
          if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl) {
              $(this).parent().addClass('active');
          }
          if ((($(this).attr("href") == 'index.php')||($(this).attr("href") == '')) && (pgurl == '')) {
              $(this).parent().addClass("active");
          }
      })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try changing

```
<?php if ((basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '.php')) == 'portfolio' or 'portfolioItem') echo "class='active'";?>>
```

to

```
<?php if ( (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '.php')) == 'portfolio.php' || (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '.php')) == 'portfolioItem.php'  ) { echo "class='active'"; }  ?>>
```

Comment: I have just edited my answer by adding {  and } and corrected = to ==

Comment: Good. Have a nice christmas !